# attribute not sent to controller from view

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

In a spring mvc application using hibernate, a JSP is not passing a populated value for an object called `code` of type `CPTCode` when the user clicks the submit button after selecting a value for `code` from the drop down list in the form.  As a result, I am getting a null pointer exception when the controller method for the jsp runs.  **Can someone show me how to fix my code so that the null pointer error goes away and the controller can see the `code` which the user selected?**

The `code` is selected from a preset of list of possible codes, and a reference to the `code` is then added to an arraylist property of an `Encounter` entity which has a ManyToMany relationship with `CPTCode`.

Here is the JSP:

```
<html lang="en">
<jsp:include page="../fragments/headTag.jsp"/>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <jsp:include page="../fragments/bodyHeader.jsp"/>
    <c:set var="method" value="put"/>
    <h2>Codes</h2>
    <form:form modelAttribute="code" method="${method}" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="control-group" id="patient">
            <label class="control-label">Patient </label>
            <c:out value="${encounter.patient.firstName} ${encounter.patient.lastName}"/>
            ${encounter.dateTime}
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <form:select path="${code}" items="${encountercodes}" size="5" style="min-width:600px"/>
        </div>
        <td></td>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit">Add a Billing Code</button> <h3>    Link to delete will go here.</h3>
        </div>
    </form:form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/patients/{patientId}/encounters/{encounterId}/codes", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String initUpdateCodesForm(@PathVariable("encounterId") int encounterId, Map<String, Object> model) {
    System.out.println("--------------------------------- made it into initUpdateForm() method");
    Encounter encounter = this.clinicService.findEncounterById(encounterId);
    CPTCode code = new CPTCode();
    model.put("code", code);
    model.put("encounter", encounter);
    return "encounters/createOrUpdateCodesForm";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/patients/{patientId}/encounters/{encounterId}/codes", method = {RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.POST})
public String processUpdateCodesForm(@ModelAttribute("code") CPTCode code, @PathVariable("encounterId") int eid, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
    Encounter encounter = this.clinicService.findEncounterById(eid);
    System.out.println("-------- code.id and code.name are: "+code.getId()+", "+code.getName());//null error here
    int maxId = 0;
    for(int u=0;u<encounter.getCodes().size();u++){
        if(encounter.getCodes().get(u).getId()>maxId){
            maxId = encounter.getCodes().get(u).getId();
        }
    }
    code.setId(maxId+1);
    encounter.addCode(code);
    System.out.println("... in processUpdateCodesForm() just did encounter.addCode(code)");
    this.clinicService.saveEncounter(encounter);
    System.out.println("..... encounter.id, encounter.codes.size are: "+encounter.getId()+", "+encounter.getCodes().size());
    return "redirect:/encounters?encounterID={encounterId}";
}
```

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.model.CPTCode.getId(CPTCode.java:30) ~[CPTCode.class:na]
    at org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.web.EncounterCodeController.processUpdateCodesForm(EncounterCodeController.java:104) ~[EncounterCodeController.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_29]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219) ~[spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) ~[spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:849) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812) [spring-webmvc-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:74) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.web.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:73) [datatables-core-0.9.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.servlet2.filter.DatatablesFilter.doFilter(DatatablesFilter.java:71) [datatables-servlet2-0.9.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [catalina.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.42]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [na:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_29]
```

**The code for the entities can be read at a file sharing site by clicking on the links below:**

The code for the `Encounter` entity can be read [at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/HZa6rUaQ2rYT6fZFUGqD?b=5kGXnbu644ibC8sVfoQU).
The code for the `CPTCode` entity can be read [at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/6Js8X9MyHTQXLkoVKs6j?b=YVOTdxQ2hU1Skab8oAvn).
The code for the `Patient` class can be found [at this link.](https://jumpshare.com/v/eSaA7nuBrn5Qfe1dt6Ag?b=logu4CZgD0uCTRMxiWNA)
The code for `Person` is [at this link.](https://jumpshare.com/v/4sdK4xTom7mW1kC5JV0g?b=tBqbKukTRbNlUYM0Dio5)
The code for `BaseEntity` is [at this link.](https://jumpshare.com/v/rYHzIV7P3fQKZ4qEalZD?b=ndIjMOqNwwx0mryvcvHM)

**NOTE:**

Deleting the line `<form:select path="${code}" items="${encountercodes}" size="5" style="min-width:600px"/>` eliminates the error message, but also deletes the drop down list, which is central to this JSP.  How can I get the drop down list to work?

Comment: show other class as well

Comment: @Rembo I added links to `Patient`, `Person` and `BaseEntity` to the end of my original posting above.  Do you see that the error is being thrown at the `System.out.println()` command on the third line of the `PUT/POST` method in the controller code that I posted higher up in my original posting above? It is saying the `code` object coming back from the JSP is null.  I need the `code` object from the JSP to transfer the id of a user-chosen `CPTCode` to be stored in the `codes` property of the given `Encounter` object.

Comment: i will check. come oneline [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48426/discussion-between-rembo-and-codemed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your stacktrace message :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.samples.knowledgemanager.model.CPTCode.getId(CPTCode.java:30) ~[CPTCode.class:na]
```

it means the `id` attribute of `CPTCode` is null, when you use it, that time will raise a `NullPointerException`.

So, To get work your code, change the following:

To add a select box with CPTCode in your form, modify like:

```
 <form:form modelAttribute="encounter" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="${actUrl}">
    <div class="control-group">
        <form:select path="codeSelected" items="${encountercodes}" size="5" style="min-width:600px"/>
    </div>
    <form:hidden path="id"/>
    <td>
    </td>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit">Add a Billing Code</button> <h3>    Link to delete will go here.</h3>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

then, add a variable `private Integer codeSelected;` to your `Encounter` class, with getter and setter.

Populate encountercodes in your controller like:

```
@ModelAttribute("encountercodes") 
public Map populateEncountercodes() { 
   Map<Integer, String> encCodes = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>(); 
   for(CPTCode cpt: this.clinicService.findEncountercodes()){ 
     encCodes.put(cpt.getId(), cpt.getName()); 
   } 
   return encCodes; 
}
```

And In your POST modify like:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/patients/{patientId}/encounters/{encounterId}/codes", method = {RequestMethod.POST}) 
    public String processUpdateCodesForm(@ModelAttribute("encounter") Encounter encounter,            
@PathVariable("encounterId") int eid, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) { 
       Encounter myencounter = this.clinicService.findEncounterById(eid); 
       CPTCode myCode = this.clinicService.findCPTCodeById(encounter.getCodeSelected()); 
       myencounter.addCode(myCode); 
       return "redirect:/encounters?encounterID={encounterId}"; 
    }
```

Comment: +1 and thank you very much for taking the time to study this with me.

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC is trying to get values out of your CPTCode object

```
CPTCode.getId(CPTCode.java:30)
```

But they are null since you are passing in an emtpy object

```
CPTCode code = new CPTCode();
model.put("code", code);
```

Populate some values into `code`, have your class initialize values in the default constructor, or have your Class return defaults in the getters so you are not returning null.

I suggest you consider familiarizing yourself with the [Null Object Pattern.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern%E2%80%8E)

Comment: the dropdownlist in the jsp is full of values for codes.  the user selects one of those values and clicks the submit button, only to get the null pointer error.

Comment: That's because the id in your CPTCode object is null. You need to provide a value.

Comment: why not delete the lines `CPTCode code = new CPTCode();
model.put("code", code);` and let `code` come from the user's selection from `encountercodes` in the jsp?  Is there some way I can change the jsp to allow this?

Comment: I'm sure there is. I'm not fortunate enough to work in Spring MVC enough to know it off the top of my head. The app I work on uses Struts :(

Answer (score 0):

Remove the drop down and fist try with a

```
<form:form modelAttribute="code" method="${method}" class="form-horizontal">

     <input type='text' name="id" name='id' value='100'>




   <div class="form-actions">
   <button type="submit">Add a Billing Code</button> <h3>    Link to delete will go here.</h3>
   </div>
  </form:form>
```

try this and you it should work.. So you will able to follow this to lists too :)

Comment: Deleting `<form:select path="${code}" items="${encountercodes}" size="5" style="min-width:600px"/>` eliminates the error message, but it also eliminates the drop down list which is central to this JSP.  How can I add the drop down list back in and have it work?