# Map has size limited to 3 elements

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to populate a Map in Java, but for some reason it is not letting the map have more than 3 elements, even though I want more.  How can I fix this?

Here is the java code, which happens to be in a controller method in a spring mvc application:

```
@ModelAttribute("addLinkOptions") 
public Map loadLinkOptions(){ 
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> addLinks = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>(); 
    addLinks.put("/calendar?day=2014-01-10","New this"); 
    System.out.println(" ......1 size of addlinks is: "+addLinks.size());
    addLinks.put("/","New that"); 
    System.out.println(" ......2 size of addlinks is: "+addLinks.size());
    addLinks.put("/otherlink","New some other thing"); 
    System.out.println(" ......3 size of addlinks is: "+addLinks.size());
    addLinks.put("/","New dog"); 
    System.out.println(" ......4 size of addlinks is: "+addLinks.size());
    addLinks.put("/","New cat"); 
    System.out.println(" ......5 size of addlinks is: "+addLinks.size());
    addLinks.put("/","New Car"); 
    System.out.println(" ......6 size of addlinks is: "+addLinks.size());
    addLinks.put("/","New lizard"); 
    System.out.println(" ......7 size of addlinks is: "+addLinks.size());
    addLinks.put("/","New bike"); 
    System.out.println(" ......8 size of addlinks is: "+addLinks.size());
    addLinks.put("/","New motorcycle"); 
    System.out.println(" ......9 size of addlinks is: "+addLinks.size());
    addLinks.put("/","New frog"); 
    System.out.println(" ......10 size of addlinks is: "+addLinks.size());
    return addLinks;
}  

 ......1 size of addlinks is: 1
 ......2 size of addlinks is: 2
 ......3 size of addlinks is: 3
 ......4 size of addlinks is: 3
 ......5 size of addlinks is: 3
 ......6 size of addlinks is: 3
 ......7 size of addlinks is: 3
 ......8 size of addlinks is: 3
 ......9 size of addlinks is: 3
 ......10 size of addlinks is: 3
 ......10 size of addlinks is: 3
```

Comment: Most of your keys are identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A map is a key/value store, every key is unique, adding value with the same key will override the previous value with that key.

Comment: +1 and thanks for the fast response.  I fixed the problem by using another answer which said something similar.

Comment: I am marking yours as the answer even tho the other guy was 2 minutes faster, because you don't have any points yet.  Do you want to answer another question?  Here is the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031119/attribute-not-sent-to-controller-from-view

Answer (score 2):

A `Map` only has one element for each key.  so when you call

```
addLinks.put("/","New dog");
```

it *deletes* the old entry for `/` and replaces it with `"New dog"`.

I can't tell what you actually want here: maybe a `Map<String, List<String>>` or a `ListMultimap<String, String>` from a third-party library like Guava?

Comment: They will each link to different things, but for testing I was just keeping them the same. I took your advice and gave them each different values, which eliminated the problem. +1 and thanks for the fast response.

Comment: I have another java question.  Are you willing to answer it?  Here is the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031119/attribute-not-sent-to-controller-from-view

Comment: @CodeMed: No, I'm not.  (Not least because I've deliberately avoided having to know anything about Spring, Hibernate, _or_ JSP.)

Comment: No worries.  And thank you again for the fast response. I gave +1 and would have marked yours as the accepted answer if you did not have 1000 times the number of points as the person who also gave the correct answer 2 minutes later.  I figured you would not notice the 15 points, while I was able to double his points.